# I want to find nearest place from a selected point(latitude, longitude) and it also filter by type

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search all place which have type="3BHK"
this is my table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `house` (
`ad_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
`lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
`lng` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`price` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`contact_number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ad_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;



$sql = "SELECT ad_id,lat,lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('".$mylat."') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('".$mylong."') ) + sin( radians('".$mylat."') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM house where type LIKE '%3BHK%' ORDER BY distance HAVING distance < 1";
```

Comment: It looks like you have a good idea on how you want to do this. What are you stuck on?

Comment: when i search nearest place , its working fine.. but when i use type filter.. its not working.. its show that no result found...

Comment: Can you specify _'its not working'_ do you get an error, do you get no records? Your query looks fine at first glance. Check the return value of `mysqli_query` (false means it failed) then call `mysqli_error` to get a descriptive error.

Comment: This actually proves that the query **does** work, just you probably do not have any records that satisfy the criteria or you made a mistake when you wrote the query

Comment: Btw, mysql has spatial data types and functions that could simplify these calculations.

Comment: can u tell me about this spatial data type? @shadow

Comment: Well, you could have typed "mysql spatial" expression into google yourself, but here you go: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html For functions you can start here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance

Comment: Thanks all.. This query working...